# Substract data in R

Tags: r, set-difference

So I have a data which is

```
data = read.csv("CarPrice_Assignment.csv")
```

Then i described numdata if the data set is a num variable

```
numdata = select_if(data, is.numeric)
```

I want to describe other data that is in data but not it numdata as categorical data. How to substract data-numdata?
I've tried using

```
catdata = setdiff(data,numdata)
```

But it doesn't work for columns. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `catdata = setdiff(names(data),names(numdata))` if you want their names or `select(data, -any_of(names(numdata)))` if you want the data.frame

Comment: `catdata <- data %>% select(where(Negate(is.numeric)))`